# python 2D list with average of surrounding cells in original 2D list

Tags: python, matrix

I need to write a function blur(l) that replaces each cell in a 2D matrix (i.e. a 2D list that is rectangular) with the average of its neighbors and itself. Each cell has at most 8 neighbors, hence the average is computed over at most 9 cells. The only thing you may assume about the given list is that it is rectangular, and that it only contains integers.

**! this has to be done without numpy !**

I tried using this code:

```
def blur(l):
    result = []
    for x in range(len(l) - 1):
        tussen = []
        for y in range(len(l) - 1):
            t = get_neighbor_sum(l, x, y)
            tussen.append(t)
        result.append(tussen)
    return result

def get_value(list, i, j):
    new_i = len(list) - 1
    new_j = len(list[new_i]) - 1
    print(i, j, new_i, new_j)
    return list[new_i][new_j]


def get_neighbor_sum(list, i, j):
    sum = 0
    for offset_i in [-1, 0, 1]:
        for offset_j in [-1, 0, 1]:
            sum += get_value(list, i + offset_i, j + offset_j)
    return sum
```

but for some reason it only returns the original list, can someone explain me why and how to fix this?

Comment: just a question for clarification: whats the use of get_value? if you already have the list, why dont you just get the value inside of get_neighbour_sum?

Comment: `get_value` seems bugged. It doesn't pay attention to the `i` and `j` passed to it

Comment: For what it's worth, SpartanHero, this question was well-asked, clear, and about as far from a "gimme the codez" question as we ever see on StackOverflow. Fully worthy of answering and as far from plagiarism as a sentence is from a spellchecker.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

def get_neighbors(lst, point):
    x,y = point
    neighbors = []
    for offset_x, offset_y in itertools.product([-1, 0, 1], repeat=2):
        new_x, new_y = x + offset_x, y + offset_y
        try:
            neighbors.append(lst[new_y][new_x])
        except IndexError:
            continue
    return neighbors
```

This should give you all the values of the neighboring cells in `lst` with respect to the point `point` (which should be a tuple of the form `(column, row)`). From there you should be able to iterate through your list and replace that element with `sum(result)/len(result)`.

```
for y, row in enumerate(lst):
    for x, _ in enumerate(row):
        result = get_neighbors(lst, (x, y))
        lst[y][x] = sum(result) / len(result)
```

You could even blur the results a bit more by changing your `get_neighbors` function to accept a parameter for how wide an offset to search and how strong a weight to give to each offset.

```
import itertools

def get_neighbors(lst, point, n=1, weights=None):
    if weights is None:
        weights = dict()
    x, y = point
    neighbors = []
    offsets = range(-n, n+1)
    for offset_x, offset_y in itertools.product(offsets, repeat=2)):
        new_x, new_y = x + offset_x, y + offset_y
        weight = weights.get(new_y, {}).get(new_x, 1)
        # defaults to 1.
        # Same as try: weights[new_y][new_x] except KeyError: 1
        try:
            neighbors.append(lst[new_y][new_x] * weight)
        except IndexError:
            continue
    return neighbors
```

This expects that weights is a dict of dicts that defines how much weight should be given to an offset x and y, such as:

```
{-1: {-1: 0.5,
       0: 1,
       1: 0.5},
  1: {-1: 0.5,
       0: 1,
       1: 0.5}}
```

Any missing keys are assumed to have full weight, so this would give half weight to the squares marked as `X` below

```
X O X
O O O
X O X
```

There might be a nicer implementation but I can't think of one off-hand :)

Answer (score 0):

get_value() is supposed to check whether the indexes you are feeding the function are valid for the list. If they indexes are not valid, get_neighbor_sum() should not add them, In the corners, the average value could only be between four values. This is difficult to do with two functions, because we have to return a value for get_value() that is invalid (a float maybe), have the get_neighbor_sum() notice this and not add it...

I think that you don't need the function get_value() at all, and can make it easier by making a get_neighbor_average function:

```
def get_neighbor_average(list, i, j):
    sum = 0
    div = 0
    for offset_i in [-1, 0, 1]:
        for offset_j in [-1, 0, 1]:
            new_i = i + offset_i
            new_j = j + offset_j
            if (new_i >= 0 and new_j >= 0 and new_i < len(list) and new_j < len(list)):
                sum += list[new_i][new_j]
                div += 1
    avg = sum / div
    return avg
```

This gives you an average of all the neighbors, but is safe because it checks whether the list element we are trying to access is valid or not.

Comment: Thanks, typo, wanted to use list index.

Comment: only other comment is to be careful how you index. Since you have `i, j` as `which row, which columns` instead of the more usual `(x, y)` notation (`which column, which row`). This isn't broken, but needs to be carefully documented as it's easy to miss

Comment: thanks this seems to work much better, but how do I implement this function in my other function? (blur(l))